# Linq: GroupBy its child.value property value

Tags: c#, .net, linq, group-by

I have a class `Parent` with a collection of `Child` objects, where `Child` has two properties: `Key` and `Value`:

```
class Parent
{
    public IEnumerable<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

class Child
{
    public String Key { get; set; }
    public String Value { get; set; }
}
```

I need to group a `List<Parent>` by its `Child.Value`.

Example:

```
IEnumerable<Parent> parents = new List<Parent>()
{ 
    new Parent()
    {
        Children = new List<Child>()
        {
            new Child() { Key = "key1", Value = "v1" },
            new Child() { Key = "key1", Value = "v2" }
        }
    },
    new Parent()
    {
        Children = new List<Child>()
        {
            new Child() { Key = "key1", Value = "v2" },
            new Child() { Key = "key1", Value = "v3" }
        }
    }
};
```

Any approach?

Comment: Firstly, I'd advise you to ditch the "C" prefix, which is very unconventional in .NET. (I'd then advise you to use "Children" for the property name, and if you're using C# 6, use an automatically implemented read-only property.) The code you've provided won't even compile as you're trying to use `Chlids` as if it's writable, and you're using `ArrayList` which doesn't implement the generic `IEnumerable<T>`. Please provide a real [mcve] - and be clear about exactly what you mean - there are *multiple* children, so how can you group a parent by "its child value"?

Comment: I've changed your suggestions. Yes, I need to group a parent by **each child.Value** value.

Comment: `ArrayList` isn't a generic type - your code is still invalid, which means you haven't compiled it. You haven't changed the name of the `CChild` class either. Basically, this still isn't a [mcve] - we need to be able to copy, paste, compile and run, at least as far as you've got - and you need to provide examples of what output you expect. We really don't know what result you want here...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
var query =
    from p in parents
    from c in p.Children
    group p by c.Value;
```

This gives:

[image: query]

---

You can also use this:

```
var query =
    parents
        .SelectMany(p => p.Children, (p, c) => new { p, c })
        .GroupBy(x => x.c.Value, x => x.p);
```

---

This is a query that works even if `Children` is `null` or an empty enumerable:

```
var query =
    parents
        .SelectMany(p =>
            (p.Children ?? new Child[] { })
                .DefaultIfEmpty(new Child() { Value = null }),
            (p, c) => new { p, c })
        .GroupBy(x => x.c.Value, x => x.p);
```

Comment: Thanks @Enigmativity .Could you use `parents.Where(f => ...)`-like notation?

Comment: One of those few times where query syntax is actually more readable than method chaining :)

Comment: I've posed a short approach of my problem. I need to use `method chaining`.

Comment: @Jordi - Done as requested.

Comment: @Enigmativity Could you provide an example taking in mind that `parents` may not have children? Therefore, each `parent` whitout children should be grouped by a `null` value. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use chained `Linq`'s [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`GroupBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var result = parents
    .SelectMany(parent => parent.Children,
               (parent, child) => new { Key = child.Value, Parent = parent })
    .GroupBy(x => x.Key,
             x => x.Parent);
```

What it logically does is:

- For each `Child` (using the flattening [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany(v=vs.110).aspx)) select the `Child`'s `value` as a `Key` and its `Parent`
- Now that you have a collection of `Key`-`Parent` pairs - group those by the `Key` while taking only the parent instead of the whole pair.